# Delete confirmation message in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I am using jquery datatables in my asp.net mvc application. I just want to enable confirmation popup when user presses the delete button for particular row. i cant find any solution over the internet that works. below is my script for datatable in razor view.

**Razor View Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#example').dataTable({

    //scrollY: "300px",
    //scrollX: false,
    //scrollCollapse : true,
    //"iDisplayLength": 100,
    //"iDisplayStart": 0,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/UsersAPI/LoadUsers",
    //"sServerMethod": "POST",
    //"sAjaxDataProp": "",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "Id", "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "mData": "Email", "sWidth": "30%" },
        { "mData": "FirstName", "sWidth": "25%" },
        { "mData": "LastName", "sWidth": "25%" },
        { "mData": "RoleName", "sWidth": "40%" },
        { "mData": "AccountName", "sWidth": "40%" },
      {

          "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
              //return data + ' ' + row[3];
              return '<a href=' +
                           '@Url.Action("Edit", "Users")?Email=' + row.Email +
                        '>Edit</a>';
          }              
      },
      {

          "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
              //return data + ' ' + row[3];
              return '<a href=' +
                           '@Url.Action("Delete", "Users")?Id=' + row.Id +
                        '>Delete</a>';
          }
      }
      ]

});
```

Comment: Suggest you consider changing you link to a form. A delete action is changing data so it should be a POST, not a GET. You don't want this being added to the browser history, of have a user just type it in the address bar. At best you will be making an unnecessary database call to delete something which does not exist and at worst it may throw an exception depending on your code.

Answer (score 2):

I would assign a class to the delete link :

```js
"mRender": function (data, type, row) {
              return '<a class="delete" href=' +
                     '@Url.Action("Delete", "Users")?Id=' + row.Id +
                     '>Delete</a>';
           }
```

By that it should be no problem to cancel a click on the delete link :

```js
$("a.delete").on('click', function() {
    return confirm('Really delete?');
});
```

Comment: That solution does not work. it does not even ask for confirmation. no errors.